# leaps for stepwise selection: issues with factor variables

Tags: r, regression, stepwise-regression

I'm trying to use the forward stepwise selection from the package leaps in order to choose the best predictors for a logistic regression.
This is the structure of my database

```
spec_tbl_df [7,397 x 19] (S3: spec_tbl_df/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
     $ X1                     : num [1:7397] 9617 12179 9905 5745 10067 ...
     $ Administrative         : num [1:7397] 5 26 4 3 7 16 4 3 2 0 ...
     $ Administrative_Duration: num [1:7397] 408 1562 58 103 165 ...
     $ Informational          : num [1:7397] 2 9 2 0 1 3 4 5 0 0 ...
     $ Informational_Duration : num [1:7397] 47.5 503.7 28.5 0 28.5 ...
     $ ProductRelated         : num [1:7397] 54 183 82 25 115 86 75 23 27 33 ...
     $ ProductRelated_Duration: num [1:7397] 1547 9676 4729 1109 3428 ...
     $ BounceRates            : num [1:7397] 0 0.0111 0 0 0 ...
     $ ExitRates              : num [1:7397] 0.01733 0.0142 0.01454 0.00167 0.01629 ...
     $ PageValues             : num [1:7397] 0 19.57 9.06 61.3 4.97 ...
     $ SpecialDay             : num [1:7397] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
     $ Month                  : Factor w/ 10 levels "Aug","Dec","Feb",..: 8 8 8 1 8 4 8 7 8 8 ...
     $ OperatingSystems       : Factor w/ 8 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 2 3 2 2 2 3 3 4 8 2 ...
     $ Browser                : Factor w/ 13 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 5 ...
     $ Region                 : Factor w/ 9 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 3 2 1 6 4 8 1 1 7 3 ...
     $ TrafficType            : Factor w/ 19 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 2 12 2 5 10 4 2 4 2 1 ...
     $ VisitorType            : Factor w/ 3 levels "New_Visitor",..: 3 3 3 1 3 3 3 3 1 3 ...
     $ Weekend                : Factor w/ 2 levels "FALSE","TRUE": 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
     $ Revenue                : Factor w/ 2 levels "FALSE","TRUE": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
```

The target variable to be predicted is Revenue (which is a factor variable that takes only 2 boolean values).

The first time I run the function it showed up the months inside the variable "Month" as they were predictors. Same for the variable "Visitor Type" and for "Weekend", but not for "Region" (so I assume you can actually use factor variables with leaps). Below the code and the output:

```
fwd.regfit=regsubsets(Revenue~. ,shoppers_train, method = "forward", nvmax = 20)
    summary.fwd.regfit=summary(fwd.regfit)
    summary.fwd.regfit

    1 subsets of each size up to 20
    Selection Algorithm: forward
              X1  Administrative Administrative_Duration Informational Informational_Duration ProductRelated ProductRelated_Duration
    1  ( 1 )  " " " "            " "                     " "           " "                    " "            " "                    
    2  ( 1 )  " " " "            " "                     " "           " "                    " "            " "                    
    3  ( 1 )  " " " "            " "                     " "           " "                    " "            " "                    
    4  ( 1 )  " " " "            " "                     " "           " "                    " "            "*"                    
    5  ( 1 )  " " " "            " "                     " "           " "                    " "            "*"                    
    6  ( 1 )  " " "*"            " "                     " "           " "                    " "            "*"                    
    7  ( 1 )  " " "*"            " "                     " "           " "                    " "            "*"                    
    8  ( 1 )  " " "*"            " "                     " "           " "                    " "            "*"                    
    9  ( 1 )  " " "*"            " "                     " "           " "                    " "            "*"                    
    10  ( 1 ) " " "*"            " "                     " "           " "                    " "            "*"                    
    11  ( 1 ) " " "*"            " "                     " "           " "                    " "            "*"                    
    12  ( 1 ) " " "*"            " "                     " "           " "                    " "            "*"                    
    13  ( 1 ) " " "*"            " "                     " "           " "                    " "            "*"                    
    14  ( 1 ) " " "*"            " "                     "*"           " "                    " "            "*"                    
    15  ( 1 ) " " "*"            " "                     "*"           " "                    " "            "*"                    
    16  ( 1 ) " " "*"            " "                     "*"           " "                    " "            "*"                    
    17  ( 1 ) " " "*"            " "                     "*"           " "                    " "            "*"                    
    18  ( 1 ) "*" "*"            " "                     "*"           " "                    " "            "*"                    
    19  ( 1 ) "*" "*"            " "                     "*"           " "                    " "            "*"                    
    20  ( 1 ) "*" "*"            " "                     "*"           " "                    " "            "*"                    
              BounceRates ExitRates PageValues SpecialDay MonthDec MonthFeb MonthJul MonthJune MonthMar MonthMay MonthNov MonthOct
    1  ( 1 )  " "         " "       "*"        " "        " "      " "      " "      " "       " "      " "      " "      " "     
    2  ( 1 )  " "         " "       "*"        " "        " "      " "      " "      " "       " "      " "      "*"      " "     
    3  ( 1 )  " "         "*"       "*"        " "        " "      " "      " "      " "       " "      " "      "*"      " "     
    4  ( 1 )  " "         "*"       "*"        " "        " "      " "      " "      " "       " "      " "      "*"      " "     
    5  ( 1 )  " "         "*"       "*"        " "        " "      " "      " "      " "       " "      " "      "*"      " "     
    6  ( 1 )  " "         "*"       "*"        " "        " "      " "      " "      " "       " "      " "      "*"      " "     
    7  ( 1 )  " "         "*"       "*"        " "        " "      " "      "*"      " "       " "      " "      "*"      " "     
    8  ( 1 )  " "         "*"       "*"        " "        " "      " "      "*"      " "       " "      " "      "*"      " "     
    9  ( 1 )  " "         "*"       "*"        " "        " "      " "      "*"      " "       " "      " "      "*"      " "     
    10  ( 1 ) " "         "*"       "*"        " "        " "      " "      "*"      " "       " "      " "      "*"      " "     
    11  ( 1 ) "*"         "*"       "*"        " "        " "      " "      "*"      " "       " "      " "      "*"      " "     
    12  ( 1 ) "*"         "*"       "*"        " "        " "      " "      "*"      " "       " "      " "      "*"      " "     
    13  ( 1 ) "*"         "*"       "*"        " "        " "      " "      "*"      " "       " "      " "      "*"      "*"     
    14  ( 1 ) "*"         "*"       "*"        " "        " "      " "      "*"      " "       " "      " "      "*"      "*"     
    15  ( 1 ) "*"         "*"       "*"        " "        " "      " "      "*"      " "       " "      " "      "*"      "*"     
    16  ( 1 ) "*"         "*"       "*"        "*"        " "      " "      "*"      " "       " "      " "      "*"      "*"     
    17  ( 1 ) "*"         "*"       "*"        "*"        "*"      " "      "*"      " "       " "      " "      "*"      "*"     
    18  ( 1 ) "*"         "*"       "*"        "*"        "*"      " "      "*"      " "       " "      " "      "*"      "*"     
    19  ( 1 ) "*"         "*"       "*"        "*"        "*"      " "      "*"      " "       " "      "*"      "*"      "*"     
    20  ( 1 ) "*"         "*"       "*"        "*"        "*"      " "      "*"      "*"       " "      "*"      "*"      "*"     
              MonthSep OperatingSystems Browser Region TrafficType VisitorTypeOther VisitorTypeReturning_Visitor WeekendTRUE
    1  ( 1 )  " "      " "              " "     " "    " "         " "              " "                          " "        
    2  ( 1 )  " "      " "              " "     " "    " "         " "              " "                          " "        
    3  ( 1 )  " "      " "              " "     " "    " "         " "              " "                          " "        
    4  ( 1 )  " "      " "              " "     " "    " "         " "              " "                          " "        
    5  ( 1 )  " "      " "              " "     " "    " "         " "              "*"                          " "        
    6  ( 1 )  " "      " "              " "     " "    " "         " "              "*"                          " "        
    7  ( 1 )  " "      " "              " "     " "    " "         " "              "*"                          " "        
    8  ( 1 )  " "      " "              " "     " "    " "         " "              "*"                          "*"        
    9  ( 1 )  " "      "*"              " "     " "    " "         " "              "*"                          "*"        
    10  ( 1 ) " "      "*"              "*"     " "    " "         " "              "*"                          "*"        
    11  ( 1 ) " "      "*"              "*"     " "    " "         " "              "*"                          "*"        
    12  ( 1 ) " "      "*"              "*"     "*"    " "         " "              "*"                          "*"        
    13  ( 1 ) " "      "*"              "*"     "*"    " "         " "              "*"                          "*"        
    14  ( 1 ) " "      "*"              "*"     "*"    " "         " "              "*"                          "*"        
    15  ( 1 ) "*"      "*"              "*"     "*"    " "         " "              "*"                          "*"        
    16  ( 1 ) "*"      "*"              "*"     "*"    " "         " "              "*"                          "*"        
    17  ( 1 ) "*"      "*"              "*"     "*"    " "         " "              "*"                          "*"        
    18  ( 1 ) "*"      "*"              "*"     "*"    " "         " "              "*"                          "*"        
    19  ( 1 ) "*"      "*"              "*"     "*"    " "         " "              "*"                          "*"        
    20  ( 1 ) "*"      "*"              "*"     "*"    " "         " "              "*"                          "*"
```

After some reasearch online I tried to use the function "ungroup" on my tibble database. Terrible idea, things got worse:

```
Subset selection object
Call: regsubsets.formula(Revenue ~ ., shoppers_train, method = "forward", 
    nvmax = 20)
68 Variables  (and intercept)
                             Forced in Forced out
X1                               FALSE      FALSE
Administrative                   FALSE      FALSE
Administrative_Duration          FALSE      FALSE
Informational                    FALSE      FALSE
Informational_Duration           FALSE      FALSE
ProductRelated                   FALSE      FALSE
ProductRelated_Duration          FALSE      FALSE
BounceRates                      FALSE      FALSE
ExitRates                        FALSE      FALSE
PageValues                       FALSE      FALSE
SpecialDay                       FALSE      FALSE
MonthDec                         FALSE      FALSE
MonthFeb                         FALSE      FALSE
MonthJul                         FALSE      FALSE
MonthJune                        FALSE      FALSE
MonthMar                         FALSE      FALSE
MonthMay                         FALSE      FALSE
MonthNov                         FALSE      FALSE
MonthOct                         FALSE      FALSE
MonthSep                         FALSE      FALSE
OperatingSystems2                FALSE      FALSE
OperatingSystems3                FALSE      FALSE
OperatingSystems4                FALSE      FALSE
OperatingSystems5                FALSE      FALSE
OperatingSystems6                FALSE      FALSE
OperatingSystems7                FALSE      FALSE
OperatingSystems8                FALSE      FALSE
Browser2                         FALSE      FALSE
Browser3                         FALSE      FALSE
Browser4                         FALSE      FALSE
Browser5                         FALSE      FALSE
Browser6                         FALSE      FALSE
Browser7                         FALSE      FALSE
Browser8                         FALSE      FALSE
Browser9                         FALSE      FALSE
Browser10                        FALSE      FALSE
Browser12                        FALSE      FALSE
Browser13                        FALSE      FALSE
Region2                          FALSE      FALSE
Region3                          FALSE      FALSE
Region4                          FALSE      FALSE
Region5                          FALSE      FALSE
Region6                          FALSE      FALSE
Region7                          FALSE      FALSE
Region8                          FALSE      FALSE
Region9                          FALSE      FALSE
TrafficType2                     FALSE      FALSE
TrafficType3                     FALSE      FALSE
TrafficType4                     FALSE      FALSE
TrafficType5                     FALSE      FALSE
TrafficType6                     FALSE      FALSE
TrafficType7                     FALSE      FALSE
TrafficType8                     FALSE      FALSE
TrafficType9                     FALSE      FALSE
TrafficType10                    FALSE      FALSE
TrafficType11                    FALSE      FALSE
TrafficType13                    FALSE      FALSE
TrafficType14                    FALSE      FALSE
TrafficType15                    FALSE      FALSE
TrafficType16                    FALSE      FALSE
TrafficType17                    FALSE      FALSE
TrafficType18                    FALSE      FALSE
TrafficType19                    FALSE      FALSE
TrafficType20                    FALSE      FALSE
VisitorTypeOther                 FALSE      FALSE
VisitorTypeReturning_Visitor     FALSE      FALSE
WeekendTRUE                      FALSE      FALSE
Browser11                        FALSE      FALSE
1 subsets of each size up to 21
Selection Algorithm: forward
          X1  Administrative Administrative_Duration Informational Informational_Duration ProductRelated ProductRelated_Duration
1  ( 1 )  " " " "            " "                     " "           " "                    " "            " "                    
2  ( 1 )  " " " "            " "                     " "           " "                    " "            " "                    
3  ( 1 )  " " " "            " "                     " "           " "                    " "            " "                    
4  ( 1 )  " " " "            " "                     " "           " "                    " "            "*"                    
5  ( 1 )  " " " "            " "                     " "           " "                    " "            "*"                    
6  ( 1 )  " " "*"            " "                     " "           " "                    " "            "*"                    
7  ( 1 )  " " "*"            " "                     " "           " "                    " "            "*"                    
8  ( 1 )  " " "*"            " "                     " "           " "                    " "            "*"                    
9  ( 1 )  " " "*"            " "                     " "           " "                    " "            "*"                    
10  ( 1 ) " " "*"            " "                     " "           " "                    " "            "*"                    
11  ( 1 ) " " "*"            " "                     " "           " "                    " "            "*"                    
12  ( 1 ) " " "*"            " "                     " "           " "                    " "            "*"                    
13  ( 1 ) " " "*"            " "                     " "           " "                    " "            "*"                    
14  ( 1 ) " " "*"            " "                     " "           " "                    " "            "*"                    
          BounceRates ExitRates PageValues SpecialDay MonthDec MonthFeb MonthJul MonthJune MonthMar MonthMay MonthNov MonthOct
1  ( 1 )  " "         " "       "*"        " "        " "      " "      " "      " "       " "      " "      " "      " "     
2  ( 1 )  " "         " "       "*"        " "        " "      " "      " "      " "       " "      " "      "*"      " "     
3  ( 1 )  " "         "*"       "*"        " "        " "      " "      " "      " "       " "      " "      "*"      " "     
4  ( 1 )  " "         "*"       "*"        " "        " "      " "      " "      " "       " "      " "      "*"      " "     
5  ( 1 )  " "         "*"       "*"        " "        " "      " "      " "      " "       " "      " "      "*"      " "     
6  ( 1 )  " "         "*"       "*"        " "        " "      " "      " "      " "       " "      " "      "*"      " "     
7  ( 1 )  " "         "*"       "*"        " "        " "      " "      "*"      " "       " "      " "      "*"      " "     
8  ( 1 )  " "         "*"       "*"        " "        " "      " "      "*"      " "       " "      " "      "*"      " "     
9  ( 1 )  " "         "*"       "*"        " "        " "      " "      "*"      " "       " "      " "      "*"      " "     
10  ( 1 ) " "         "*"       "*"        " "        " "      " "      "*"      " "       " "      " "      "*"      " "     
11  ( 1 ) " "         "*"       "*"        " "        " "      " "      "*"      " "       " "      " "      "*"      " "     
12  ( 1 ) "*"         "*"       "*"        " "        " "      " "      "*"      " "       " "      " "      "*"      " "     
13  ( 1 ) "*"         "*"       "*"        " "        " "      " "      "*"      " "       " "      " "      "*"      " "     
14  ( 1 ) "*"         "*"       "*"        " "        " "      " "      "*"      " "       " "      " "      "*"      "*"     
          MonthSep OperatingSystems2 OperatingSystems3 OperatingSystems4 OperatingSystems5 OperatingSystems6 OperatingSystems7
1  ( 1 )  " "      " "               " "               " "               " "               " "               " "              
2  ( 1 )  " "      " "               " "               " "               " "               " "               " "              
3  ( 1 )  " "      " "               " "               " "               " "               " "               " "              
4  ( 1 )  " "      " "               " "               " "               " "               " "               " "              
5  ( 1 )  " "      " "               " "               " "               " "               " "               " "              
6  ( 1 )  " "      " "               " "               " "               " "               " "               " "              
7  ( 1 )  " "      " "               " "               " "               " "               " "               " "              
8  ( 1 )  " "      " "               " "               " "               " "               " "               " "              
9  ( 1 )  " "      " "               " "               " "               " "               " "               " "              
10  ( 1 ) " "      "*"               " "               " "               " "               " "               " "              
11  ( 1 ) " "      "*"               " "               " "               " "               " "               " "              
12  ( 1 ) " "      "*"               " "               " "               " "               " "               " "              
13  ( 1 ) " "      "*"               " "               " "               " "               " "               " "              
14  ( 1 ) " "      "*"               " "               " "               " "               " "               " "              
          OperatingSystems8 Browser2 Browser3 Browser4 Browser5 Browser6 Browser7 Browser8 Browser9 Browser10 Browser11 Browser12
1  ( 1 )  " "               " "      " "      " "      " "      " "      " "      " "      " "      " "       " "       " "      
2  ( 1 )  " "               " "      " "      " "      " "      " "      " "      " "      " "      " "       " "       " "      
3  ( 1 )  " "               " "      " "      " "      " "      " "      " "      " "      " "      " "       " "       " "      
4  ( 1 )  " "               " "      " "      " "      " "      " "      " "      " "      " "      " "       " "       " "      
5  ( 1 )  " "               " "      " "      " "      " "      " "      " "      " "      " "      " "       " "       " "      
6  ( 1 )  " "               " "      " "      " "      " "      " "      " "      " "      " "      " "       " "       " "      
7  ( 1 )  " "               " "      " "      " "      " "      " "      " "      " "      " "      " "       " "       " "      
8  ( 1 )  " "               " "      " "      " "      " "      " "      " "      " "      " "      " "       " "       " "      
9  ( 1 )  " "               " "      " "      " "      " "      " "      " "      " "      " "      " "       " "       " "      
10  ( 1 ) " "               " "      " "      " "      " "      " "      " "      " "      " "      " "       " "       " "      
11  ( 1 ) " "               " "      " "      " "      " "      " "      " "      " "      " "      " "       " "       " "      
12  ( 1 ) " "               " "      " "      " "      " "      " "      " "      " "      " "      " "       " "       " "      
13  ( 1 ) " "               " "      " "      " "      " "      " "      " "      " "      " "      " "       " "       " "      
14  ( 1 ) " "               " "      " "      " "      " "      " "      " "      " "      " "      " "       " "       " "      
          Browser13 Region2 Region3 Region4 Region5 Region6 Region7 Region8 Region9 TrafficType2 TrafficType3 TrafficType4
1  ( 1 )  " "       " "     " "     " "     " "     " "     " "     " "     " "     " "          " "          " "         
2  ( 1 )  " "       " "     " "     " "     " "     " "     " "     " "     " "     " "          " "          " "         
3  ( 1 )  " "       " "     " "     " "     " "     " "     " "     " "     " "     " "          " "          " "         
4  ( 1 )  " "       " "     " "     " "     " "     " "     " "     " "     " "     " "          " "          " "         
5  ( 1 )  " "       " "     " "     " "     " "     " "     " "     " "     " "     " "          " "          " "         
6  ( 1 )  " "       " "     " "     " "     " "     " "     " "     " "     " "     " "          " "          " "         
7  ( 1 )  " "       " "     " "     " "     " "     " "     " "     " "     " "     " "          " "          " "         
8  ( 1 )  " "       " "     " "     " "     " "     " "     " "     " "     " "     " "          "*"          " "         
9  ( 1 )  " "       " "     " "     " "     " "     " "     " "     " "     " "     " "          "*"          " "         
10  ( 1 ) " "       " "     " "     " "     " "     " "     " "     " "     " "     " "          "*"          " "         
11  ( 1 ) " "       " "     " "     " "     " "     " "     " "     " "     " "     " "          "*"          " "         
12  ( 1 ) " "       " "     " "     " "     " "     " "     " "     " "     " "     " "          "*"          " "         
13  ( 1 ) " "       " "     " "     " "     " "     " "     " "     " "     "*"     " "          "*"          " "         
14  ( 1 ) " "       " "     " "     " "     " "     " "     " "     " "     "*"     " "          "*"          " "         
          TrafficType5 TrafficType6 TrafficType7 TrafficType8 TrafficType9 TrafficType10 TrafficType11 TrafficType13
1  ( 1 )  " "          " "          " "          " "          " "          " "           " "           " "          
2  ( 1 )  " "          " "          " "          " "          " "          " "           " "           " "          
3  ( 1 )  " "          " "          " "          " "          " "          " "           " "           " "          
4  ( 1 )  " "          " "          " "          " "          " "          " "           " "           " "          
5  ( 1 )  " "          " "          " "          " "          " "          " "           " "           " "          
6  ( 1 )  " "          " "          " "          " "          " "          " "           " "           " "          
7  ( 1 )  " "          " "          " "          " "          " "          " "           " "           " "          
8  ( 1 )  " "          " "          " "          " "          " "          " "           " "           " "          
9  ( 1 )  " "          " "          " "          " "          " "          " "           " "           "*"          
10  ( 1 ) " "          " "          " "          " "          " "          " "           " "           "*"          
11  ( 1 ) " "          " "          " "          " "          " "          " "           " "           "*"          
12  ( 1 ) " "          " "          " "          " "          " "          " "           " "           "*"          
13  ( 1 ) " "          " "          " "          " "          " "          " "           " "           "*"          
14  ( 1 ) " "          " "          " "          " "          " "          " "           " "           "*"          
          TrafficType14 TrafficType15 TrafficType16 TrafficType17 TrafficType18 TrafficType19 TrafficType20 VisitorTypeOther
1  ( 1 )  " "           " "           " "           " "           " "           " "           " "           " "             
2  ( 1 )  " "           " "           " "           " "           " "           " "           " "           " "             
3  ( 1 )  " "           " "           " "           " "           " "           " "           " "           " "             
4  ( 1 )  " "           " "           " "           " "           " "           " "           " "           " "             
5  ( 1 )  " "           " "           " "           " "           " "           " "           " "           " "             
6  ( 1 )  " "           " "           " "           " "           " "           " "           " "           " "             
7  ( 1 )  " "           " "           " "           " "           " "           " "           " "           " "             
8  ( 1 )  " "           " "           " "           " "           " "           " "           " "           " "             
9  ( 1 )  " "           " "           " "           " "           " "           " "           " "           " "             
10  ( 1 ) " "           " "           " "           " "           " "           " "           " "           " "             
11  ( 1 ) " "           " "           " "           " "           " "           " "           " "           " "             
12  ( 1 ) " "           " "           " "           " "           " "           " "           " "           " "             
13  ( 1 ) " "           " "           " "           " "           " "           " "           " "           " "             
14  ( 1 ) " "           " "           " "           " "           " "           " "           " "           " "             
          VisitorTypeReturning_Visitor WeekendTRUE
1  ( 1 )  " "                          " "        
2  ( 1 )  " "                          " "        
3  ( 1 )  " "                          " "        
4  ( 1 )  " "                          " "        
5  ( 1 )  "*"                          " "        
6  ( 1 )  "*"                          " "        
7  ( 1 )  "*"                          " "        
8  ( 1 )  "*"                          " "        
9  ( 1 )  "*"                          " "        
10  ( 1 ) "*"                          " "        
11  ( 1 ) "*"                          "*"        
12  ( 1 ) "*"                          "*"        
13  ( 1 ) "*"                          "*"        
14  ( 1 ) "*"                          "*"
```

As you can see each level inside my factor variables is treated as a predictor itself.
I want a single column "Month" to be treated as a possibile predictor, not every single month. Same for the other factor variables.

How can I fixt it ?

Comment: Stepwise regression is not valid.  See https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/stepwise-regression-problems/

Comment: This is an assignment I have to stick up with. But thanks anyway for your.. help.

Comment: If I were the instructor you'd get extra credit for bootstrapping the entire process to quantify stability of selected predictors.

Comment: An answer is here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64167138/regsubsets-is-generating-dummy-variables-from-factor-levels-can-we-make-it-not